# ¿Cómo crear un directorio en Django?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

Por medio de una `view` quiero crear una nueva carpeta en mi carpeta `static`, en el servidor de Django, ¿se puede hacer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sí se puede. Solo tienes que importar el módulo `os` y usar el método `mkdir()`.

Algo así:

```
import os

os.mkdir('/ruta/al/directorio/', mode=0755)
```

Los argumentos son:

- `/ruta/` que puede ser relativa
- `mode` que es la representación en octal de los permisos de acceso al nuevo directorio.

Si prefieres hacerlo con [Unipath](https://github.com/mikeorr/Unipath#creating-renaming-removing), puedes hacer algo como esto:

```
from unipath import Path

>>> ruta = Path('.', 'directorio')
>>> ruta.isdir()
False
>>> ruta.mkdir()
>>> ruta.isdir()
True
```

El método que utilices depende solo de tus gustos.

Comment: Al importarlo en el terminal me sale un error.

ImportError: No module named unipath

Comment: Claro @A.Castro, primero tienes que instalar el módulo.

Comment: No tengo conocimiento de como instalarlo, sabes de alguna guía?

Comment: @A.Castro con `pip`, busca en Google como instalar paquetes con `pip`.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import os

os.mkdir('/ruta/al/directorio/', mode=0o755)
```

Observa que he escrito `0o` antes de los dígitos, de esta manera le dices que interprete `755` como un numero octal que es la interpretación correcta de los permisos de linux, si no pones lo pones interpretará el numero como decimal y los derechos serán incorrectos.

Curiosamente si empleas cosas como mingw (o gitbash) que es un emulador de linux el comando funciona con o sin el prefijo 0o  porque mingw se monta sobre windows